# moderncv - bibliography entries CATEGORIZED and ORDER by year

Tags: bibliographies, moderncv

I am trying to include my publication in my cv and in particular I would like to:

- divide them for typology: i.e. published papers, working papers, conference presentations
- order the items in each of the group by decreasing year.

This is a MWE

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

    \moderncvstyle{casual}
    \moderncvcolor{black}
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \rfoot{\addressfont\itshape\textcolor{gray}{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
    \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.7cm}

    \firstname{Frank}
    \familyname{Pins}

    \renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
      \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\bfseries#3}%
    %   \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}% I changed this line (with comma) ...
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{ {\slshape#4}}% ... into this one (without comma).
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
        .\strut%
        \ifx&#7&%
          \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \renewcommand{\refname}{Publications\subsection{Papers}}
    \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[{\arabic{enumiv}}]}
    \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{1.8cm}
    \nocite{A}
    \nocite{B}
    \renewcommand{\refname}{Publications\subsection{Working Papers}}
    \nocite{C}
    \nocite{D}
    %\bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{references} 

    \end{document}
```

Where the reference.bib file has the following entries:

```
    @Unpublished{C,
      Title                    = {Hi},
      Author                   = {Me, myself},
      Note                     = {Available at },
      Year                     = {2014}
    }
    @Unpublished{D,
      Title                    = {Hi 2},
      Author                   = {Me, myself},
      Note                     = {Available at },
      Year                     = {1800}
    }

    @article{A,
    author = {Me, myself},
    title = {Hi3},
    journal = {journaltitle},
    volume={2},
    year={2014}
    }
    @article{B,
    author = {Me, myself},
    title = {Hi3},
    journal = {journaltitle},
    volume={2},
    year={1900}
    }
```

What should I do? Any help?

Thank

Ginu

Comment: Is there a way to insert the year on the left column of the modernCv?

Answer (score 2):

Easily done with the modern combo of `biblatex` and `biber`. Choose a style that serves your needs.

[image: ginuModerncvBibSections]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @Unpublished{C,
        Title                    = {Hi},
        Author                   = {Me, myself},
        Note                     = {Available at },
        Year                     = {2014}
    }
    @Unpublished{D,
        Title                    = {Hi 2},
        Author                   = {Me, myself},
        Note                     = {Available at },
        Year                     = {1800}
    }

    @article{A,
        author = {Me, myself},
        title = {Hi3},
        journal = {journaltitle},
        volume={2},
        year={2014}
    }
    @article{B,
        author = {Me, myself},
        title = {Hi3},
        journal = {journaltitle},
        volume={2},
        year={1900}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{black}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.7cm}

\firstname{Frank}
\familyname{Pins}




\usepackage[sorting=ydnt,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\nocite{*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\printbibheading[title=Publications]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=unpublished,title={Working Papers}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=article,title={Papers}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @johannes_B, thanks for the quick reply. 
When I try to do it myself i do not get the publications listed. I just get the black bar and the title Publication.
When I compile bibliography I get these errors: 
      The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
      I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
      I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
      I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
      (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited normally

Comment: Remove all the auxiliary files and compile using `biber`. [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)

Comment: I doesn't work either. I got this error Undefined control sequence \endentry . Could you please help?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Comment: I have miktex 2.9

Comment: Have you copied the example, as is, and compiled it? If the error happens when you implement it in your reald document, there could still be some stuff from previous compiles in the helper files, corrupting the current run.

Comment: I am just copying and pasting your answer. Then I modified he default bibliography to Biber and compiling it by latexbiber latex.
When I run biber I have the warning WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.6, expected version 1.7

Comment: Seems like your biber version is terribly old. Are you running MikTeX 64 bit? If so, you need to get the latest biber from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.9/binaries/Windows/). Nevertheless, updating the system will be a good idea.

Comment: hey johannes, sorry again but I can't figure it out how to update biber. I am working with 32 bit

Comment: Just like any other package, with the MikTeX package manager.

Comment: I did it but nothing changes and I still get the same error. what I can I do?

Comment: It works now. Thanks johannes really appreciated